# After publishing from Flash to HTML, How is it possible to have alternative content for non Flash devices?

Tags: javascript, html, flash-cs3

I am using Flash CS3 Pro', I have published a HTML page from it so that opens properly on all the browsers and versions etc. Is it possible to have alternative content for non Flash devices within the Flash generated Javascript within the file AC_RunActiveContent.js?
If so how do you do it?

Or is their a better way to do it?

Thankyoou,

Comment: Honestly, Flash is basically dead with regards to general web development, particularly for mobile devices.  You would best spend efforts learning to work with HTML5 canvas.

Answer (score 0):

I think this thread might help you answer your question:

http://www.dgrin.com/showthread.php?p=1370078

Answer (score 0):

You could use a javascript Flash Detector script like the one below:

https://github.com/browserstack/flashblock-detector

Then you can redirect the user to an more static page.

```
var flash = flashBlockDetect();
if (flash > 1) {
  window.location = "static-page.html";
}
```